# What metric I can use to test the prediction in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression

Let's say, I have two data set: train and test.

I applied, let' say, linear regression and CART on train data set, then use predict function to predict with test data set.

So, I will have two predictions:

Linear regression: 2.5 1.4 2.19 ...

CART: 3 5 4 2 ...

Actual test data set: 1 4 3 8 2 ...

(Of course, the numbers are just examples).

So, what metric I can use to say, which prediction method is better (in term, it predicts more precisely)?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in linear regression you can use root mean square error (RMSE) .You can also try to use MAE (Mean Absolute error) wrt actual predicted value of your test set. One advantage of RMSE is that it gives high weight to larger errors.

Comment: Hi, so can I use RMSE with CART or other prediction also. Because I need to compare them to see which is better?

Comment: yes, you can test it out on the predicted values of both. If u understand correctly

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will go with this way

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer, if you found the answer useful.